# A exercise in basic algebra Cohn

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

This question appears in *Basic Algebra* written by Cohn and really stuck on me:

> Let $G$ be a group and $K, L, N$ be subgroups such that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $K$, $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, $[L, K] = K$, $KL = G$, and $[L, N] = 1$. Show that $N$ lies in the center of $K$.

Note: If $A$ and $B$ are subgroups of a group $G$, then $[A, B]$ denote the subgroup of $G$ generated by all commutators $[a, b]$, where $a ∈ A$, $b ∈ B$.

Can anyone solve it out?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As $K=[K,L]$ each element $k$ of $K$ is a product of commutators like $x:=k_1^{-1}(l^{-1}k_1l)$.

For each $n\in N$ we will have that $n^{x}=n^{k_1^{-1}l^{-1}k_1l}$.

Now use the facts  that $N$ is normalised by $K$ and that $L$ commutes with $N$ to simplify this,
$$
n^{x}
=n^{k_1^{-1}l^{-1}k_1l}
=n^{k_1^{-1}k_1l}
=n^{l}
=n.
$$

Hence we will have $n^{k}=n$ for all $k\in K$ and $n\in N$.